# facebook graph api result now displaying

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

just wanted to ask why does my facebook graph api is not returning any result but it does work in my localhost.  Does it have anything to do with my hosting site(ipage)?

here is the code:

```
$FBpage = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/26484009688027  /members?access_token=***&limit=300');

$FBdata = json_decode($FBpage);

foreach ($FBdata->data as $tcc_members ) {

$StatusID = explode("_", $tcc_members->id);
echo '<li>';
if (!empty($tcc_members->name)) {  

echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'.$tcc_members->id.'/picture?type=square"';
echo "$tcc_members->name";
} 
echo '</li>'; }
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked your settings @ `developers.facebook.com?`, specifically the `app domains` & `site url`?

Comment: but how come it works in my localhost? if it has something to do with the settings in my facebook apps.

Comment: you will need 1 app domain for each site you run it on, so if locally your url is `myapp.local` and on live your url is `myapp.com`, they both should be specified in your app settings.

Answer (score 1):

When I try your query on the [Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), I get an error that the ID you are requesting `26484009688027` does not exist. Check your ID again.

Another issue is with white space in your URL. This may be a problem.

Some hosts disable the `file_get_contents` php function. You can create a php file with just this code to see:

```
<?php echo ini_get('allow_url_fopen') ? "Enabled" : "Disabled";
```

Finally, `file_get_contents` is not the best way to access the Facebook API. You should really be using cURL or the [Facebook PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php)

Comment: it lacks 2 at the end of the id, should be 264840096880272, it is a group page by the way.

Comment: i run your code and it echoed disabled, does it mean ipage hosting does not support file_get_contents?

Comment: It means you can't use file_get_contents or cURL until it is enabled. Contact customer support and see what it takes to enable it. You may be able to do it with an `ini_set` call.